# Jquery validate value greater or equal, does not work, why?

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-validate

I have a two select fields with year options. I wanna control them with jquery validation plugin in that way so the second select field "bis" must be greater or equal to the first one "von"... Now I made a script, but it does not work in a right way.

Error message does not get removed on correction of values, and I don't know how to fix it, is problem somewhere in validation or in hiding of elements with classes...

I hope that there is someone who can help me to setup this validation to work nice..

Situation in jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dzorz/CbKZq/

html:

```
<div class="container">
<form id="addEntry" method="post" action=''>
<fieldset>
        <select class="span2 von" id="von" name="von">
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="2016">2016</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
        </select>
        <select class="span2 bis" id="bis" name="bis">
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="2016">2016</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
        </select>
            <button type="submit">apply</button>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div class="year_container">
    </div>
</diV>
```

script

```
$("#addEntry").validate(
    {
        rules:{ 

        },
        messages:{

        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            $(element).filter(':not(.valid)').addClass("invalid");
            error.appendTo($('.year_container'));

        },
        success: function(error) {
            $("#addEntry").find('.valid').removeClass("invalid").addClass("success");
            $(".year_container").find('.error').hide('.error');
        },
    });

jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterOrEqualThan", function(value, element, params) {

    if (!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value))) {
        return new Date(value) >= new Date($(params).val());
    }

    return isNaN(value) && isNaN($(params).val()) 
    || (Number(value) > Number($(params).val())); 
},'end year must be greater or equal than/to start year.');

$(".bis").rules('add', { greaterOrEqualThan: ".von" });
```

css

```
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.error{
   display:inline !important;
   color: red !important;
}

.invalid {
    border: 1px solid red !important;
}

.success{
    border: 1px solid green !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `errorPlacement` and `success` functions are part of the problem.  The main problem though is that when `.vis` changes, Validate does not re-check `.bis` to make sure it's still `greaterOrThanEqualThan`.  So to solve the main problem, add this code:

```
$('.von').change(function(){$('.bis').valid();});
```

I think you can achieve what you were trying to do in your validate options using existing options `errorLabelContainer`, 'errorClass', and `validClass` (see the [docs](http://validation.bassistance.de/validate/) for details).

```
$("#addEntry").validate({
    errorLabelContainer: '.year_container',
    validClass: 'success',
    errorClasss: 'invalid'
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/CbKZq/1/

Answer (score 1):

use this it working

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterThan", function(value, element, params) {

        if ($(params[0]).val() != '') {    
            if (!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value))) {

    //console.log("innder",new Date(value).getTime() >= new Date($(params[0]).val()).getTime());
                return new Date(value).getTime() >= new Date($(params[0]).val()).getTime();
            }    
            return isNaN(value) && isNaN($(params[0]).val()) || (Number(value) > Number($(params[0]).val()));
        };
        return true; 
    },'Expiry date Must be greater  than and equal to {1}.');
```

usage

```
rules: {
               'promo[expire_date]': {
                    required:true,
                    greaterThan: ["#start_date","Start Date"]              
                },
            }
```